# Probability $Pr(W<R)$ of two Normal Random Variables $W$ and $R$.

Tags: probability

Let $R$~$Normal(μ_R,σ_R^2)$ and $W$~$Normal(μ_W,σ_W^2)$

Also $μ_W=4μ_R$ and $σ_W=4σ_R$

I have to calculate $Pr(W<R)$ or equivalently $Pr(\frac{W}{R}<1)$

I've got this far:

Let $Y=\frac{R-μ_R}{σ_R}$ so $Y$~$N(0,1)$ and $Z=\frac{W-μ_W}{σ_W}$ so $Z$~$N(0,1)$

Then $\frac{Z}{Y}$~$Cauchy$ from which I could use the pdf of the Cauchy-distribution to answer my question. But I can't get $\frac{W}{R}<1$ in the form $\frac{Z}{Y}=a$ for a constant $a$, so I'm at a dead-end with this idea.

Is there something I'm missing at the end or is this the complete wrong way to go about answering this question?

Comment: are $R$ and $W$ independent?

Comment: Yes they are, sorry.

Comment: I think you should follow the hint of BCLC

Comment: "$Pr(W<R)$ or equivalently $Pr(\frac{W}{R}<1)$" These are NOT equivalent consider for example $W(\omega)=-3$ and $R(\omega)=-2$.

Comment: @Refnom95 Include independence in OP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use BCLC's advice.

The ratio distribution of two normal random variables with non-zero means is complicated.

The PDF of $X \sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$ ratio $Z = X/Y$ is given by:

$$p_Z(z)= \frac{b(z) \cdot d(z)}{a^3(z)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_x \sigma_y} \left[\Phi \left( \frac{b(z)}{a(z)}\right) - \Phi \left(-\frac{b(z)}{a(z)}\right) \right] + \frac{1}{a^2(z) \cdot \pi \sigma_x \sigma_y } e^{- \frac{c}{2}} $$

where

$$a(z)= \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma_x^2} z^2 + \frac{1}{\sigma_y^2}} $$

$$b(z)= \frac{\mu_x }{\sigma_x^2} z + \frac{\mu_y}{\sigma_y^2} $$

$$c = \frac{\mu_x^2}{\sigma_x^2} + \frac{\mu_y^2}{\sigma_y^2} $$

$$d(z) = e^{\frac{b^2(z) - ca^2(z)}{2a^2(z)}} $$

$$\Phi(t)= \int_{-\infty}^{t}\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{- \frac{1}{2} u^2}\ du\ $$

Comment: Thanks for the support but does this answer the question?

Comment: @BCLC I neither believed nor wanted him to accept my answer. But my answer give him insight about his problem and on why another method is  better. And to be fair lately most one line hint answers have been deleted because they should instead be comments. (Not that i agree with that tho) Personally i think both our answers are ok, but not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Instead compute

$$P(W-R < 0)$$

Comment: Note that the sum (or difference) of two normal random variables is itself normal.